# Lagrangian density invariace under $\phi_{a} \rightarrow \phi_{a} + \theta\epsilon_{abc}n_{b}\phi_{c} $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

PROBLEM

Verify that the Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{a}\partial^{\mu}\phi_{a}-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi_{a}\phi_{a}$$
for a triplet of real fields $\phi_{a} (a = 1, 2, 3)$ is invariant under the infinitesimal $SO(3)$ rotation by θ:
$$\phi_{a} \rightarrow \phi_{a} + \theta\epsilon_{abc}n_{b}\phi_{c} $$
$$\phi_{a} \rightarrow \phi_{a} + \delta\phi_a $$

SOLUTION

We need $$\delta\mathcal{L}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi_{a})}\delta \partial_{\mu}\phi_{a}+\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi_{a}}\delta\phi_{a}=0 $$

$$\delta\mathcal{L}=\partial^{\mu}\phi_{a}\partial_{\mu}\theta\epsilon_{abc}n_{b}\phi_{c} - m^2\phi_a \theta \epsilon_{abc}n_b\phi_c=\theta\epsilon_{abc}n_b(\partial^{\mu}\phi_{a}\partial_{\mu}\phi_{c} - m^2\phi_a\phi_c) $$
Here also with Euler-Lagrange equation $m^2\phi_a+\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\phi_a=0$ I'm stuck.

Comment: What have the Euler-Lagrange equations to do with the problem?

Comment: Is a relationship that could perhaps be useful to cancel the parenthesis but not. I need to proof that $\delta \mathcal{L}=0$

Comment: Focus on the antisymmetric matrix structure constant acting on a symmetric parenthesis tensor. You *don't* need the E-L eqns. Delete your question?

Comment: No, you do not need the equations of motion here. It would be a disaster if you would because then the SO(3) invariance may not hold at the quantum level.